# Tools to assist with printing of Google Maps route

Tags: firefox, maps, printing

Say I have played with my Google Maps directions and gotten to the point that they look good and I'm ready to print. What is a good procedure for doing that, retaining control over formatting?

The best I've found so far for this is the Firefox Add-on "Print Edit." It's better than the default print -- I can get rid of graphics, for example -- but it doesn't give me as much control as I'd like.

Would prefer Firefox if possible, but I'm willing to use a different browser if that helps.

Comment: What "control" do you need?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - Thank you for asking.  I would like to be able to do some reformatting.  With Print Edit, I have learned to remove graphics such as left-turn arrows, which is nice because it saves toner.  But sometimes Google Maps inserts weird extra steps and I find it tedious to remove little bits and pieces with Print Edit.  Also, I would like to reformat the mileage information Google Maps provides.  Those are examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked my Print Edit procedure, and in the Preview step, I increased the zoom to 150%.  Looks great!